# Getting access to MainWindow.xaml.cs properties from outsourced ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I am working on a new **UserControl** lately and I have to make it customizable, which wasn't a problem until I figured out, that I have to put the **DataTemplates** in an **external ResourceDictionary** in order to make the Control even more customizable.

So what do I have?
I have a very customizable UserControl, which is able to call a constructor
with a so-called "templatePath" from which the **ResourceDictionary will be loaded in the UserControl.Resources**. Everything works just fine!

So what's the problem?
The DataTemplates, which are now in a sepperate ResourceDictionary should be able to be bound to Properties of the UserControl.xaml(.cs) in order to check i.E. if a specific object is selected.

But that's not the only problem. Furthermore the UserControl has **predefined Commands**, that should be able to be bound to the DataTemplates. This wasn't a problem before when the DataTemplates were still in UserControl.xaml obviously.

The bad thing is, I really have to **outsource the DataTemplates**, because the control will be available to users only as .dll and in this case, there wouldn't be any opportunity to add custom Templates afterwards.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could implement this?
Thanks in advance!

**€dit**: 
This would be, for example, the ResourceDictionary, which will be dynamically loaded when the UserControl will be displayed:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:CustomControl"
>
<classes:CompareNodes x:Key="CompareNodes"/>

<Style x:Key="BorderHighlightStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Value="True">
                    <Condition.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompareNodes}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
                            <Binding Source="{Binding ???????????}" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Condition.Binding>
                </Condition>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you see, I have no clue how I could bind to the SelectedItem-Property which is declared in UserControl.xaml(.cs).

Comment: To me, your requirements (external custom templates) suggest that a Custom Control could be a better solution. Any reason why you can't do that instead?

Comment: Well I created a new control. Doesn't that make it custom anyway? Or do you mean that I have to make a whole new class deriving from Control? I don't know exactly how that would help me. In addition to that I would have to start again from the beginning i suppose. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oops, I misread DataTemplates as ControlTemplates. Scratch what I said. Can you post some xaml/code examples that illustrate each of the two problems you have?

Comment: I will add some code later on. Right now I am making a break. But I don't think that code will be needed. The setup isn't complex. It just that I have no idea how to access the properties. So I have a file Templates.xml (ResourceDictionary), which contains the DataTemplates which will be loaded into the UserControl.xaml. UserControl.xaml has the property "SelectedItem". Now I have to make a Trigger i.E. for a DataTemplate and ask if the Item (DataContext of the DataTemplate) is the same as the "SelectedItem" in UserControl.xaml.

Comment: Obviously binding to the property "SelectedItem" won't work because the ResourceDictionary doesn't know UserControl.xaml(.cs). I think it's an architecture failure, but there has to be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

I created a class called "BindableProperties", which has all Properties, that should be bindable from the outside (i.E. "SelectedItem") and some Commands. After that I added a "BindableProperties" object to my ResourceDictionary, which will then by loaded into my control.

In my control, I read out the "BindableProperties"-Object from the ResourceDictionary and gave it the Commands I want to bind to. Everytime the selected item changes, the BindableProperties-Object gets a new "selectedItem", therefore it stays the same as in the control.

The good thing is, that the object inside the class and the object in the ResourceDictionary are now the same, which allows me to bind to the Properties of "BindableProperties", which has the same properties as my UserControl.

**Problem solved.**